# Вычислить и вывести кол-во элементов побочной диагонали матрицы matrix, значение которых кратно 3

Tags: c#, .net

объясните как это делается на c#: Вычислить и вывести кол-во элементов побочной диагонали матрицы matrix, значение которых кратно 3. И желательно с главной диагональю. Матрица генерируется, размерность вводит пользователь.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите размер матрицы: ");
            bool ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int size);
            if (size < 0 && size > 7)
                throw new Exception("Введены невалидные данные!");
            int[,] matrix = new int[size, size];
            Random generator = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Матрица: ");
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = generator.Next(-10, 10);
                    Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                    if (matrix[i, j] % 3 == 0)
                        counter++;        
                }
                Console.Write($"Количесто кратныx элементов: {counter}\n");
            }
        }
```

Изменил код выше на:

```
Console.WriteLine("Матрица: ");
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = generator.Next(-10, 10);
                    Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                    if (matrix[i, size - i - 1] % 3 == 0)
                        counter++;        
                }
                Console.Write($"Количесто кратныx элементов: {counter}\n");
            }
```

Comment: А что собственно непонятно?

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин непонятно, как это на шарпе записывается.

Comment: Ээээ.... А в Вашем вопросе разве не шарп?

Comment: Если использовать проверку на кратность 3 в цикле заполнения, то нужно ввести условие проверки принадлежности к побочной диагонали. Однако не указано, что это за диагональ

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин шарп

Comment: @MBo int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = generator.Next(-10, 10);
                    Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                    if (matrix[i, size - i - 1] % 3 == 0)
                        counter++;        
                }
                Console.Write($"Количесто кратныx элементов: {counter}\n");
            }

Comment: Здесь нечитабельно. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Прости, не могу понять в чём проблема. Что Вам объяснить?

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин Я не могу понять как посчитать кол-во элементов побочной диагонали матрицы.

Comment: Матрица всегда квадратная?

Comment: Да, похоже на то

Comment: В таком случае один индекс берётся i, а второй - size - i. Ну или size - i - 1. Тут уже сам отладь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (j == size - i - 1)
       if (matrix[i, j] % 3 == 0)
                    counter++;
```

Но более выгодно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = generator.Next(-10, 10);
                Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
            }
            if (matrix[i, size - i - 1] % 3 == 0)
                    counter++;        
       }
Console.Write($"Количесто кратныx элементов: {counter}\n");
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не могли бы вы объяснить ваш первый код?

Comment: Если текущий элемент находится на побочной диагонали, то для него делаем проверку %3. А второй код после заполнения строки просто берёт элемент на той диагонали.

Comment: большое спасибо!!!